# Conversion of explicit to implicit ODEs (uniqueness & algorithm)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a an explicit function

$$x(t) = r(t)$$

and assume I can convert it into an implicit ODE, i.e. of the form

\begin{align*}
 \dot{x}(t) &= f(x(t))  \\
 x(0) &= r(0)
\end{align*}

My questions are:

1. Is there any sort of uniqueness theorem for the implicit equations that I obtain?
   For example, it seems like $x(t) = t^2$ can only transform into $\dot{x}(t) = 2\sqrt{x(t)}$, i.e. this is unique (up to a change of variables). It can't, say, transform into $\dot{x}(t) = \log x(t)$.
   Are there functions for which there are very different implicit formulations?
2. Is there a known algorithmic procedure through which a computer might be able to transform an explicit ODE into an implicit one?
   (This seems like it might be trivial, but I haven't been able to think of one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $r$ has an inverse, we see that $f$ is uniquely determined as $f(x)=r'(r^{-1}(x))$.

Comment: What if it doesn't?

Comment: Then in general you cannot find $f$. Consider for instance $x(t)=t^2\sin(1/t)$.

Comment: Oooh, totally missed that somehow since I missed that $x$ would have to be just a function of $t$ and not of other variables. Thanks!